# How to translate the %in% in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I thought I could use `%in%` on dplyr columns, but don't understand why this  example returns `FALSE`:

```
c <- tbl_df(cars)
> 4 %in% select(c,speed)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: You can't use it on columns in base R so what makes you think you can use it on columns with dplyr?

Comment: Here's the best way: `c %>% .$speed %>% \`%in%\`(4, .)` - just kidding ...

Comment: @RichardScriven I don't understand your first comment. `4 %in% cars$speed` works for me.

Comment: Right.  That works because `cars$speed` is now an atomic vector (no longer a column), whereas `4 %in% cars["speed"]` does not work.  When you do `select(c, speed)` the result is still a data frame with 1 column, the same as `cars["speed"]`.

Comment: If you use magrittr, you can do `use_series(c, speed)` to get vector, but this is the exact same as `c$speed`, so only use it for aesthetic reasons

Comment: I guess `is_in()` is the magrittr `%in%` alias. So with the above comment, `use_series(c, speed) %>% is_in(4, .)` might be a possibility for you.  Also, I've been through the dplyr index and I don't see one that mimics `%in%`

Comment: The point of `dplyr` is that everything takes in a data.frame and puts out a data.frame. Thus, outputting a data.frame, `c %>% summarise(4 %in% speed)`. To coerce it to a vector, tack on `%>% as.logical()`.

Comment: @alistaire For what I need (i.e., using the output in an `if()`) your solutions seems the most intuitive to me. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You should almost certainly be putting the `if` (or `ifelse`, if it needs to be vectorized) in a `dplyr` function instead of the other way around, which makes me think this is [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What's the context/what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @alistaire I am not sure why you are asking about the context. I am saying your solution works for me, and I was simply saying that I personally like it more for the use I am doing of the output (i.e., putting it into an `if()`)...

Comment: I ask because it's very unusual to put a chain in a condition. You're breaking the paradigm of `dplyr` (i.e. to keep everything a data.frame), so there's likely a simpler way to approach the broader problem.

Comment: Ok thanks, I suspected that my code looked to messy to be correct :) I have a `tbl_df(df)` with a col `cityNames` I want a `string` to be compared with `cityNames`. If a match is found, I want to execute a function. How can you do it without breaking dplyr paradigm? Suppose for some reason a cannot simply call the vector of values as `df$cityNames` because `cityNames` might vary (for example, I might wanna match with `cityANDstateNames`.

Answer (score 1):

In that dataframe 'c', it appears you are trying to pull all rows that are equal to 4.

This would be a filter function. Thus the following ought to get you what I believe you are seeking:

```
filter(c, speed == 4)
```

On the other hand if you are really seeking "the column[-name]s that have '4' in them" you could even do that with the following code.

```
select(c, contains('4'))
```

But that doesn't work with the cars$speed dataset example. A similar example would however work with the iris dataset and a search for column names containing 'Len' in their titles:

```
select(iris, contains('Len'))
```

> PS: I find this cheatsheet 'placemat' really helpful for quickly surveying all the data wrangling functions availabld in dplyr: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf